# How best to split a Jira project over multiple applications / services / micro-services

Tags: jira

We are using Jira to manage the flow of development of a single application in a Scrum development team.

We want to extend the usage of Jira to include the other applications and micro-services on which the main application relies.

They run with the same development team and monthly release cycle, so we'd like to share the Versions and Epics, having them affect multiple services.

We use Bamboo and Bitbucket and would like to make sure that the requirements for making a particular release is clear in Jira (tracking the links between the stories, software versions and services that need to be released).

If find it hard to see clear advice from Atlassian that points to a particular design, though suspect that components give us what we need.

Has anyone else implemented something similar.

Are components the way forward?  Or is something more bespoke / a plug-in a better route?

Comment: If you want to share versions then it has to be all in the same project. We for example extended Version with some properties, on of those is that this particular version is relevant only for this component. This is then used in validator in 'scheduling' transition for example. Our case is that we have one big project and couple of smaller ones with different release cycles, but can share some information from the big one. If the release cycle is the same then I'd use components within the same project.